# What's the best practices in code reuse between different Ruby projects?

Tags: ruby, dry, code-reuse, modularity

guys!

I'm a software developer with Java background and I'm starting some projects using a Ruby web framework (Padrino/Sinatra).

In my java projects, I usually had some "common" projects whose classes where used in several projects. For instance, I had a central authentication service, and a shared database that stored the user profiles. All my projects that used this service shared some models mapped to the user profile database.

So, despite the framework, orm lib etc., what's the best way of sharing code across several Ruby projects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides this, [ruby's gems](http://rubygems.org/) is one of the best way of reusing common parts of code. Gems have names, version numbers, and descriptions and therefore you can easily maintain up-to-date versions of these libraries, install and uninstall, manage your computer’s local installations of gems using the `gem` command, available from the command line. Gems became standard with Ruby 1.9, but before you have to use `require 'rubygems'` line in the scripts. There are several tools that help create them, for example, [bundler](http://gembundler.com/). Bundler not only tool for gem creation, but an awesome application's dependencies manager.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code into a `something.rb` file and `require` it at the top of your other script(s).

You can also use `load` instead of `require`, but `require` has the nice property that it will not include a file more than once.  Also, using `load` requires the `.rb` extension, whereas `require` does not, i.e.,

```
#some_script.rb
puts('hello world')

#another script
require 'some_script'
>> hello world

load 'some_script'
LoadError: no such file to load -- some_script
    from (irb):2:in 'load'
    from (irb):2
```

You will almost always use `require`, but `load` is an option as well if you want to use it for... whatever reason.

Comment: I think he means what is the best way to share **something.rb** across multiple project folders. I need to do this too.